# Use of unassigned local variable (Object) Created from Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

I am creating an instance of a class from a stored procedure but I get the following error:

Use of unassigned local variable 'member'

I have the following code:

```
Member member;
while (rdr.Read())
{
    member = new member(rdr.GetInt32, rdr.GetString(1)); // Populate Class from Stored Procedure
}
return member
```

I realise that the compiler does not know that the while loop will always be triggered however what is the cleanest way to solve this without creating a default constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler can't determine whether your condition *for loop* will be true and `member` would be initialized. Therefore the error.

Since you are returning `member` after the loop and instantiation is done inside the loop. It is not guaranteed that `member` would be initialized/assigned a value. `rdr.Read()` could return false in first iteration.

You can do:

```
Member member = default(Member); //null for reference type
while (rdr.Read())
{
    member = new member(rdr.GetInt32, rdr.GetString(1)) // Populate Class from Stored Procedure
}
return member;
```

The other error in your code is usage of `rdr.GetInt32`, it is a method and should have column ordinal specified like :

```
rdr.GetInt32(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :**

1. You should assign the `member` variable before `while` loop, as `compiler` could not identify wether loop will be executed for sure or not.
2. you need to specify the column number while using `GetInt32()` function.

**Solution :**

1. assign `memebr` to `null` initially.
2. use required column `index` in `GetInt32()` function.

Try This:

```
Member member=null;
while (rdr.Read())
{
    member = new member(rdr.GetInt32(0), rdr.GetString(1)); // Populate Class from Stored Procedure
}
return member;
```